# How to read Excel worksheets and write to a file asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, file-handling

I have been given a very large Excel workbook that contains 500+ sheets. Each sheet represents a store, and the rows contain transactions at that store. Each sheet layout is identical. I have been requested to write a program that loops through each sheet, pulls specific transaction data, and writes everything to one gigantic CSV file.

I know that this kind of functionality is far better suited for relational database, but I have been asked to work on this as is.

I have written a program that successfully parses the data and writes it. The problem is that it takes almost a half-hour to complete the file write when reading and writing data synchronously.

I would like to accomplish this task by reading and writing the data from each sheet asynchronously. In C#, I would prefer to use the Task Parallel library for this, but am open to other options.

I am thinking about spinning off the worker threads from a foreach loop, like so:

```
foreach( Worksheet ws in _excelApp.Worksheets)
{
    Parallel.Invoke(()=>ExportWorksheet(ws));
}
```

And then in the method (shortened for brevity):

```
private void ExportWorksheet(Worksheet ws)
{         
     using(FileStream fs = new new FileStream(fi.FullName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write, 1, true))
     {
         for(int row = 1; row < 300; row++)
         {
              for(int column = 1; column < 20)
              {
                   byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ws.Cells[row, column].Value.ToString() + ",");
                   fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.count());
              }

              fs.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\n"), 0, 2);
         } 
     }

}
```

This gives me strange results, of course.

Am I on the right track? Should I be using a different encoding? Is there a cleaner way to accomplish the async write? Are there any threading rules being broken here?

All suggestions are welcome. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping through the rows and columns you'd better use the Value property of a range (for example the ActiveRange of a WorkSheet). This contains a two dimensional array containing all the data. This increases reading performance with a factor 1000.

For the other part. I rewrote it in two parts, removing the Excel references:

```
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        //using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\x.x", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write, 1, true))
        //{
        //    for (int row = 1; row < 3 * 1000; row++)
        //    {
        //        for (int column = 1; column < 3 * 1000; column++)
        //        {
        //            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(1.ToString() + ",");
        //            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        //        }

        //        byte[] bytes2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\n");
        //        fs.Write(bytes2, 0, bytes2.Length);
        //    }
        //}

        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(@"C:\temp\x.x", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write, 1, true)))
        {
            for (int row = 1; row < 3 * 1000; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 1; column < 3 * 1000; column++)
                {
                    tw.Write(1.ToString());
                    tw.Write(',');
                }

                tw.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;

        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Time spent: {0:N0} ms.", (end - start).TotalMilliseconds));
```

The first part (which is almost identical to your code, now commented out) takes 3.670 (yes, over three thousand) seconds.
The second part (not commented out) takes 12 seconds.

Comment: Good suggestion. I was having some difficulty at work implementing the Range[row, columns], as I was getting a COM Error each time I using it. The Worksheet.Cells[row, column] did not give me the error. Also, the real worksheets are not as neat as the example; a specific range of cells needs to be gathered. I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't use Range[row, column] but Range.Value which returns an object[,] (or maybe dynamic in the latest version of the framework)

Comment: If that works then this answer is quite nice indeed.

Comment: Yes it is, but my main concern is the async file write.

Comment: You are giving good examples, but my issue is with a non-trivial amount of data, as in hundreds of sheets each with hundreds or thousands of rows to read. The current program performs the read-write much like your example, but the entire process takes a really long time. I am thinking I need to perform the read-writes in parallel. That is the reason I am attempting to use the clumsy FileStream object, as it supports Asynchronous access to files in .NET 4.0. I don't see how your answer addresses that. I did upvote though :)

Comment: I am sorry. I was just showing there are possibilities to upgrade performance, by for example not write encoding yourself but put it in some buffer. I will update the answer to use a streamed solution that performs better

Comment: @field_b: I am pretty sure that you are on the wrong track - doing the file writes asynchronously will most probably give you no reasonable performance gain. Your bottleneck seems to the number of COM calls between your C# application and the Excel process (something which I have seen in the past very often to be a bottleneck). Each `ws.Cells[row, column]` creates such a COM call, which means "interprocess communication", which is inherently slow. That's why Patrick's tip will help you: `ActiveSheet.Range.Value` will give you the whole data of a sheet in 1 COM call.

Comment: @field_b: ... a different way to attack that problem is to create your C# program as an Excel Add-In using VSTO or (my personal choice) Excel-DNA (see https://exceldna.codeplex.com/). That makes your C# program running *within the Excel process*, so every COM call will be in-process.

Comment: Maybe a weird idea, but you could also do a SaveAs in Excel saving it as CSV. I don't know the performance impact, but it would be interesting to compare the options.

Comment: OK, I understand now. Pulling in all the active cells for the sheet will allow me to use the Range object and reduce COM calls, thereby improving performance. Thanks again.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: that's not so weird, it is actually a pragmatic solution. But it has 2 drawbacks: (1) it only works when the loss of any format information stored in the original document is acceptable (2) typically one will have to read the CSV afterwards, do some reformatting/filtering etc until the file has the desired format and write a new file afterwards.

Comment: @DocBrown: I understand. Although the OP stated he had to save that much sheets I thought that when it was a one-time-operation he could do this using a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with reading Excel from C# is, generally, nasty.  All your computing time is spent trafficking with Excel - writing out CSV files takes no time at all.  It isn't worth bothering with the separate threads.

In some cases I simply saved the spreadsheet as .csv and then parsed it from there.  How this works from multiple sheets I don't know, but you might be able to page through the sheets saving them to .CSVs one by one.  Then, read the .CSVs as long strings and clean them up.